# In Radix Sort, I get munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer and Aborted (core dumped). Why?

Tags: c++, sorting, segmentation-fault, coredump, radix-sort

After the whole program executed correctly, I get **munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer** and **Aborted (core dumped)** message in the terminal.

Function for Radix Sort :

I've designed the function in the following steps:

1. Find Max value and calculate no. of digits in it.
2. run the main loop for 'd' or no. of digits times.
3. Each time in array C frequency is counted for ith element.

```
for(int i = 0 ;i < A.size(); i++){
    int t = (int(A[i]/pow(10,j))%10);
    ++C[t];                                 
}
```

4. Then a counting Sort
5. Update the value of A by B.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void Print(vector<int> &A){                         
    for(auto i =A.begin(); i!= A.end(); i++){
        cout << *i << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void radixSort(vector<int> &A){           
    int k = A[0];
    for(auto i = A.begin(); i!=A.end(); i++){       
        if(*i > k)  k =*i;
    }

    int d =0;
    while(k >0){
        k = k/10;
        d++;                                        
    }
    vector<int> result;
    for(int j =0; j <d; j++)
    {
        vector<int> C(10, 0);               // Making the array Count of k elements with all 0's
        vector<int> B(A.size());            // Output Array     
        for(int i = 0 ;i < A.size(); i++){
            int t = (int(A[i]/pow(10,j))%10);  // for taking ith value
            ++C[t];                           // Counting Frequencies of elements in Input array    
        }                                           
        for(int i=1; i<= C.size(); i++){        // Calculating no of elements occuring before postion i 
            C[i]+= C[i-1];                      // Or Calculating final postion of the value
        }
        for(int i = B.size()-1;i >= 0; i--){
            int t = (int(A[i]/pow(10,j))%10);
            B[C[t]-1] = A[i];                   // Placing the elemsnts from Input Array in Output array accoring to their position     
            --C[t];                             // Decrementing so as to place a same value on left side ( if it Exits)   
        }
        result = A = B;
    }
}
```

Main Function

```
int main(){
    vector<int> A;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i =0; i< 10; i++){
        A.push_back(rand()%1000);
    }
    cout << "Input Array : " << endl;;
    Print(A);
    radixSort(A);
    cout << "Output Sorted Array : " << endl;;
    Print(A);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not use `pow` when dealing with integer bases and exponents.  The `pow` function is a floating point function that can be inaccurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see an issue here, as C[10] is being used as an index, which is beyond last element of the vector. The easiest fix is to make C 1 element larger, and fix the count to index conversion loop:

```
        vector<int> C(11, 0);         // fix (11)
        // ...
        for(int i=1; i <= 10; i++){   // fix ( <= 10)
            C[i]+= C[i-1];
        }
```

Comment: Thank You! So much, I did'nt see it !!